# How to change the event organizer on google calendar when creating an event?

Tags: events, google-calendar-api, organizer

I'm using the Google Calendar Api to create events, I'm trying to pass the parameter organizer with the email of the person that I want to be the owner but it is not working and the organizer it is always the same creator.

Comment: check this https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/move where you can move event to another calendar which changes event's organizer

Comment: For some reason I'm getting Forbidden error particularly with move method.

Comment: But still, I need to set the organizer of the event when I create it, not after, I am trying with the "try it now" option in the google documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert?hl=pt-br  and it is not even working there when I send the organizer parameter.

Comment: whoever is creating event, only they can become the creator of the event, you can't give different name.

Comment: But the Organizer is different from the Creator, I want to change the Organizer.

Comment: Organizer is the calendar on which the "main copy" of the event lives. As per documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events it's a read-only field. You can change the organizer by performing a move action but only if the authenticated user has write access to the destination calendar.

Comment: It let me change the organizer but only for the ones that are in the same domain as the creator of the event. If I try with an email that is not in the same domain returns Not Found error. How can I do it for an email that is not in the same domain?

Comment: Hi All ,I have been trying to move specific event from Source Calendar to Targeted calendar in the sence Changing Organizer of event but as someone suggested we need to write access for Targeted Calendar so for that I did it with Acl Insert API.Now I don't want to give whole calendar events Access ,I need to give specific event.In other words change Organizer for Specific Event.Any Idea on this?